# How to Load a VRML model on PaperVision3d?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d, vrml

im very new at papervision3d, i know in order to display a .DAE model i use this

```
import flash.events.Event;
import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;

[SWF(width=640, height=480, backgroundColor=0x808080, frameRate=30)]

public class Earth extends PV3DARApp {

    private var _earth:DAE;

    public function Earth() {
        addEventListener(Event.INIT, _onInit);
        init('Data/camera_para.dat', 'Data/flarlogo.pat');
    }

    private function _onInit(e:Event):void {
        _earth = new DAE();
        _earth.load('model/amorfo.dae');
```

But how can i do in order to use VRML models (.WRL). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does papervision even support VRML models? Last I checked, it only supported Collada (DAE).